# Как исправить ошибку gradle при загрузке библиотеки room?

Tags: android, gradle, android-room, android-gradle

Эта проблема встречается на всех новых созданных проектах, когда пытаешься загрузить room. Только на одном старом проекте всё норм

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/mpp/pm20/KotlinCompilationData
```

Comment: kapr или ksp подключен к новым проектам?

Comment: В новых проектах я использую ksp